# Application level Encryption

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, web-config

I had tried to encrypt the web config, using different `ProtectionProviders` but these methods will not full-fill the security.As i can decrypt the file easily from another application:

The Method i used for encryption:

```
 public void EncryptConnString()
        {
            Configuration confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
            ConfigurationSection confStrSect = confg.GetSection(section);
            if (confStrSect != null)
            {
                confStrSect.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");                
                confStrSect.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                confg.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
            }
        }
```

If i copied the `encrypted appSettings` to another application and call the method for decryption. this will give the original data, If i attach the encrypted config file with any other application and call the method for decryption, it will get easily decrypted.

> That means; If anyone can access the config file can easily get the
>   values, through decryption.

So here my **question** is that; How can i encrypt the `web.config` with a password? or else provide an application level encryption(restrict other application to decrypt the file).

The method used for decryption:

```
public void DecryptConnString()
        {
            Configuration confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
            ConfigurationSection confStrSect = confg.GetSection(section);
            if (confStrSect != null)
            {
                confStrSect.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
                confStrSect.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                confg.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
            }
        }
```

I had tried with the following `ProtectionProviders`:

1. MyUserDataProtectionConfigurationProvider
2. DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
3. RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider

> **Note:** I have to do this programmatically so that `aspnet_regiis` will not help me

Comment: do you mean you just want to encrypt the connection strings? aspnet_regiis can do that, check out this MSDN post. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372.aspx and see if its suitable?

Comment: I have checked some similar threads; but i have to do this programatically

Comment: mind if I ask why? your app will have to have access to the key, so anyone with access to the web.config file will also have access to the key and be able to decrypt the file. are you trying to stop a determined attacker, or someone who has legitimate access to the server?

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt the web.config, if it's only to prevent unauthorized users from reading it, it would seem you have bigger problems. On a side note, as long as you don't set a custom salt/secret to encrypt it with, anything can decrypt it providing they're using the same encryptionmethod.

Comment: If it is possible, I have to create an UI for adding and maintaining web config. So that the credentials and passwords will not be disclosed with DEV team.

Comment: you're always going to have the problem of the key needs to be available to the app. could you just replace the entire connection string block with your restricted credentials before you deploy the code, or once its on the server?